# Domain shows page cannot be found if a path provided after top level domain

Tags: reactjs, dns, subdomain, aws-amplify

As the title states I have a domain that is hosting a web app if I click directly from the app to `"/login"` it goes to the required page perfectly however if a directly type in `"https://my-domain.co.uk/login"` it says page can't be found.

I have a single page web application built using React that is hosted on amplify and its domain is managed by google domains. I have added the necessary DNS records to google domain but since google domain does not have a type @ record available I employed a domain forwarding technique that was recommended.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path={"/"} element={<LandingPage />} />
    <Route path={"/sign-up-start"} element={<SignUp />} />
    <Route path={"/sign-up"} element={<SignUpForm />} />
    <Route path={"/termofuse"} element={<TermAndConsitions />} />
    <Route path={"/login"} element={<Login />} />
    <Route path="dashboard/" element={<DashboardLayout />}>
      <Route path="home" element={<DashboardHome />} />
      <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
      <Route path="status" element={<MyStatus />} />
      <Route path="account" element={<MyAccount />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path={"*"} element={<NoPageFound />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Check the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#aws-amplify) relevant to AWS-Amplify and follow what may need to be setup or configured on the hosting service to correctly serve your app. Basic gist is that it needs to return the root index.html file for all page requests into the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amplify -> App Settings -> Rewrites and redirects

Add this rule;

Source address*:

`</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>`

Target address*:

`/index.html`

Type*:

`200 (Rewrite)`